# Create a link from one array value

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have an array how can I create a link of on of the values...www.vermont.gov

This is a part of a switch:

```
case "b1": // Vermont       

    kf=  new Array("Governor : Peter Shumlin","Size in Square Miles: 9,623","Population: 626,562","Founded: March 4th 1791","www.vermont.gov")

    mb = 'images/vermontst.jpeg';
    mt = 'images/vermontbird.jpg';
    ml = 'images/vermontflower.jpeg';
    tt = "Vermont";

    break;


document.getElementById("title").innerHTML=tt;
document.getElementById("left").style.color=fg;
document.getElementById("left").style.fontSize="30px";
document.getElementById("fac").style.marginLeft="120px";
document.getElementById("fac").style.lineHeight="70px";
document.getElementById("pic").src=mb;
document.getElementById("pict").src=mt;
document.getElementById("picl").src=ml;
document.getElementById("fac").innerHTML = kf.join(" <br/> ");
```

Comment: Can you show us how you are displaying the array?

Comment: what is *displaying the array* in your case?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry I am very new to JS....I need vermont.gov to be an actual link

Comment: nothing...thnk you

Comment: As you are new here, please allow me one hint: It is very kind of you to say Thank you to some answers, but it would be even kinder to accept the best answer (this is up to you of course!). Voting (once you crossed the 15 rep points yourself) and accepting are the way to say Thx on SO. [Please read this: someone-answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Please consider to choose the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `<a>` tag and then append to it the value of the link from the array using an `index`.

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
var linkText = document.createTextNode("my title text");
a.appendChild(linkText);
a.title = "my title text";
a.href = kf[4];
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

Comment: Probably want to slap a scheme on that `kf[4]`, in the code above it ends up being a relative link, which is almost certainly not right. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the last element of your array could just be something like this:

```
"<a href='http://www.vermont.gov'>www.vermont.gov</a>"
```